# Find the general solution of this ED $ 2y''+2y'+3 y=0 $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution of this ED

$ 2y''+2y'+3 y=0 $

I want to know if the procedure I have used and the result obtained from the differential equation are correct

If an ODE solution of the type $y=e^{rt}$ is sought, it follows that $2r^2+2r+3=0$ must be satisfied, that is , $r$ must be a root of the [i]characteristic equation[/i] $2D^2+2D+3=0$
Since the roots are $\dfrac{-1}{2}\pm \dfrac{i\sqrt{5}}{2}$ it turns out that there are two solutions
$\varphi_1(t)=e^{\left(\frac{-1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}i\right)t}=e^{\frac{ -t}{2}}\left(\cos \left(\dfrac{\sqrt{5}t}{2}\right)+i\sin \left(\dfrac{\sqrt{5}t}{2 }\right)\right) \\
\varphi_2(t)=e^{\left(\frac{-1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}i\right)t}=e^{\frac{-t} {2}}\left(\cos \left(\dfrac{\sqrt{5}t}{2}\right)-i\sin \left(\dfrac{\sqrt{5}t}{2}\right )\right)$
Now, since it is assumed that real solutions are sought, it is enough to choose some linear combinations of the previous ones, and thus

$ y_1(t)=\dfrac{\varphi_1(t)+\varphi_2(t)}{2}=e^{{\frac{-t}{2}}}\cos \left(\dfrac{\sqrt{5}t}{2}\right)\\
y_2(t)=\dfrac{\varphi_1(t)-\varphi_2(t)}{2i}=e^{{\frac{-t}{2}}} sen \left(\dfrac{\sqrt{5}t}{2}\right))$

solution general is
$ y(t)=C_1e^{{\frac{-t}{2}}}\cos \left(\dfrac{\sqrt{5}t}{2}\right)+C_2e^{{\frac{-t}{2}}} sen \left(\dfrac{\sqrt{5}t}{2}\right),\,\,\,C_1,C_2\in\mathbb{R} )$

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to know if the procedure I have used and the result obtained from the differential equation are correct

Comment: @angelabayona Yes, your procedure is correct. If you use a result that establishes that all solution are in a linear space with dimension 2, you conclude that there are no other solutions.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to review it, thank you very much

Comment: Is the result I finally reached correct?

Comment: You can use [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=2y%22%2B2y%27%2B3y%3D0) to check your solution